# FutureBuilder not resolving when Tab changes with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two tabs,' **scenes** and '**schedules**' with my flutter App. The first tab is **scenes** and the second tab is **schedules**. Each tab has its own future to resolve.
On initial load, the future corresponding to the tab **scenes** is getting resolved. But whenever I am switching the tab from **scene** to **schedules**, the future associated with the tab **schedules** is not getting resolved. It neither throws an exception nor a data. Instead, the progress indicator corresponding to **schedule future** is showing without resolving the future.

Here is the code that I have done so far

```
    class Automation extends StatefulWidget {
      final int selectedIndex;//Holding current tab index

      Automation(this.selectedIndex);

      @override
      _AutomationState createState() => _AutomationState();
    }

    class _AutomationState extends State<Automation> {

      TextEditingController _startTimeController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController _endTimeController = TextEditingController();
      
      int _currentIndex = 0;
      late final List<Scene> _userScenes;
      late List<Schedule> _userSchedules = [];
      var _sceneFuture;  //Holding scene future
      var _scheduleFeature; //Holding schedule future
      late Size size; //Holding window size

      // getting scene from database
      _getScenes() async {
        try {
          final List<Scene> scenes =
          await CommonMethods.getScenes(MyApp.currentUser.id, context);
          _userScenes = scenes;          
          return _userScenes;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
          throw e;
        }
      }
       // Getting schedule from database
      _getSchedules() async {
        try {
          final schedules =
          await CommonMethods.getSchedules(MyApp.currentUser.id, context);
          print('Schedules list from _getSchedule : ' + schedules.toString());
          _userSchedules = schedules;
          return _userSchedules;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
          throw e;
        }
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        print('Init state called with index $_currentIndex');
        _startTimeController.clear();
        _endTimeController.clear();
        _sceneFuture = _getScenes();//on init state resolving only the _sceneFuture
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
        print('Build device of automation called');
        size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

        return DefaultTabController(
          initialIndex: widget.selectedIndex,
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBarWidget(
          title: 'Automation',
          fromPage: 'automation',
          callback: this.callback,
          selectedIndex: this._currentIndex,
          addSceneCallBack: this.addSceneCallBack,
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
            height: 50,
            margin:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: const Color(0xffEEEEEE),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: TabBar(
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black87,
                onTap: _onTabTap,// function will trigger on tab change
                labelStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: gradientColors),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                tabs: [
                  const Tab(
                    text: 'Scenes',  //first tab
                  ),
                  const Tab(
                    text: 'Schedules',  //second tab
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
              ),
              Center(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.60,
              child: TabBarView(
                children: <Widget>[_buildScenes(),//building widget for first tab 'scene'
                 _buildSchedules() // building widget for second tab 'schedules',<--- here is the problem,The future associated with this method is not resolving when changing tab from 'scene' to 'schedule'
                 ],
              ),
            ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
          ),
        );
      }

      // method will trigger on tab change

      _onTabTap(int index) {
        print('Tab pressed with index : ' + index.toString());
        setState(() {
          this._currentIndex = index;
          if (this._currentIndex == 1) _scheduleFeature = _getSchedules();//Trying to resolve _scheduleFuture
        });
      }

     // building view for the tab 'scene'

      Widget _buildScenes() {
        final double height = size.height;
        return FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print('snap shot got data at scene build');
          if (_userScenes.isEmpty)
            return _buildEmptyWidget('Oops...scene list is empty!');
          return Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _userScenes.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onDoubleTap: () => _deleteSceneFromList(_userScenes[index]),
              child: SimpleShadow(
                color: const Color(0xffc0c0c0),
                opacity: 0.7,
                sigma: 6,
                child: Container(
                  height: 360,
                  width: 240,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: MyApp.isDarkMode
                        ? AppConstants.WHITE_COLOUR
                        : Colors.blueGrey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        child: SimpleShadow(
                          color: const Color(0xffc0c0c0),
                          opacity: 0.7,
                          sigma: 4,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            _userScenes[index].imgUrl,
                            width: 75,
                            height: 75,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          _userScenes[index].title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: MyApp.isDarkMode
                                  ? AppConstants.DARK_COLOUR
                                  : AppConstants.WHITE_COLOUR,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                        child: Text(
                          _userScenes[index].deviceList.length.toString() +
                              ' devices',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            // color: darkGreyColor,
                            color: MyApp.isDarkMode
                                ? darkGreyColor
                                : Colors.lightGreen,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        child: CustomButton(
                          text: _userScenes[index].isActivated
                              ? 'Activated'
                              : 'Activate',
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return SceneDetailed(
                                    selectedScene: _userScenes[index],
                                    callback: this.callback,
                                    addSceneCallBack: this.addSceneCallBack,
                                  );
                                },
                                fullscreenDialog: true),
                          ),
                          maxwidth: 120,
                          minheight: 45,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
              },
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('snapshot got error at scene build');
          const String message = 'Failed to get scenes data!';
          return _buildErrorWindow(height, message);
        } else {
          print('getting data at scene view');
          return _buildSpinner(height);
        }
          },
          future: _sceneFuture,
        );
      }

    //building schedule widget for tab 'schedule'
    //This will call for the second tab schedules
    //This FutureBuilder is not getting resolved
    //It statys always in the state 'loading',neither throwing exception nor future data

      Widget _buildSchedules() {
        print('current index from _buildSchedules $_currentIndex');
        final height = size.height;
        print('Getting actual schedule');
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: _scheduleFeature,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print('future builder got schedule data');

          if (_userSchedules.isEmpty) {
            print('at _buildSchedule and user list is empty;nothing to show!');
            return _buildEmptyWidget('Oops...schedule list is empty!');
          }

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _userSchedules.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Dismissible(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            background: Container(
              height: 90,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text(
                      'Delete',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
            onDismissed: (direction) =>
                _deleteScheduleFromList(_userSchedules[index]),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return new ScheduleDetailed(
                        schedule: _userSchedules[index],
                        callback: this.callback,
                      );
                    },
                    fullscreenDialog: true),
              ),
              child: SimpleShadow(
                color: Color(0xffc0c0c0),
                opacity: 0.7,
                sigma: 4,
                child: Container(
                  height: 90,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20, right: 7),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SimpleShadow(
                        color: Color(0xffc0c0c0),
                        opacity: 0.7,
                        sigma: 4,
                        child: Transform(
                          transform:
                              Matrix4.translationValues(-20.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient:
                                    LinearGradient(colors: gradientColors),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/to-do-list.png',
                              cacheWidth: 30,
                              cacheHeight: 30,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: 180,
                            child: Text(
                              _userSchedules[index].title,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6),
                            child: Text(
                              _userSchedules[index]
                                      .deviceList
                                      .length
                                      .toString() +
                                  ' '
                                      'devices',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: darkGreyColor,
                                fontSize: 14,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        child: IconButton(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.date_range,
                            color: _userSchedules[index].startTime.length >
                                        0 &&
                                    _userSchedules[index].endTime.length > 0
                                ? darkGreyColor
                                : baseColor,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _userSchedules[index].startTime.length == 0 &&
                                    _userSchedules[index].endTime.length ==
                                        0
                                ? _openPopup(_userSchedules[index])
                                : new Container();
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          const String message = 'Error;Failed to get schedule data!';
          print('Error failed to get schedule list with scheduleFuture');
          return _buildErrorWindow(height, message);
        } else {
          print('Resolving schedule future,loading indicator is displaying');
          return _buildSpinner(height);
        }
          },
        );
      }

      Widget _buildEmptyWidget(String message) {
         ...
      }


      Widget _buildSpinner(double height) {
         ...
      }

      Widget _buildErrorWindow(double height, String message) {
            ...
      }



      @override
      void dispose() {
        _startTimeController.dispose();
        _endTimeController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you trying move
`if (this._currentIndex == 1) _scheduleFeature = _getSchedules();`
out of the use state.

I would also suggest having both as separate widgets than functions that render them.
So that you can make use of `initState` and `didDependencyChange` overrides.

Comment: I already tried your first opinion, but it has no use. About the second one, I haven't tried it yet. Even if it resolves the issue how we will extend that as a general solution?